# Stripe Retrieve Transfers for connected accounts

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Stripe API has method for retrieving transfers by transferID Transfer::retrieve($transferId);
but always return that transfer doesn't exist when I try to retrieve transfer for connected Account.

I want to send email to particular connected account when the founds will be transfered to his bank account.

How to achieve this?

Comment: you need https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header

Answer (score 2):

In the Ruby API, you can achieve this by passing in the stripe_account, like this:

```
Stripe::Transfer.retrieve(transfer_id, {:stripe_account => acct_id})
```

If you want to trigger an action on your side based on funds being transferred, you might want to use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).

Comment: For the Node API, you can do the same by passing a second parameter like so `{stripe_account: accountId};`